# MemSQL Ops schema - No databases

Tags: singlestore

I have upgraded MemSQL Ops to version 5.1.2 and deleted some unwanted nodes. Now when I click Explore > Schema I get the following error:-

```
Error: (1735, "Unable to connect to leaf @139.59.144.183:3307 with user root, using 
password NO: [2004] Cannot connect to '139.59.144.183':3307. Errno=111 (Connection refused)")

No databases
```

The leaf node on 139.59.144.183 does not show up when i run:-

```
memsql-ops memsql-list
```

It looks like the node was not completely deleted. Is there a way to manually delete a partially deleted node?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you are seeing on the schema page is there because the leaf still shows up in `show leaves` on the master aggregator. The solution is to run `REMOVE LEAF` for the offending leaf on the master aggregator directly.

More information available at https://docs.memsql.com/docs/remove-leaf